# Landlord special tzedakah for renter?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, story-identification, chassidic-rebbe

[ArtScroll's Tzedakah Treasury (p.200)](https://www.artscroll.com/Details.aspx?itemNo=9781578195145) quotes a story from "Rosh Golas Ariel" saying that the Imrei Emes told a landlord to pay his poor tenant's rent rather than have the community help pay the tzedakah because "...It's a clear sign from Heaven that this mitzvah is earmarked for you alone!"

Where is this story in Rosh Golas Ariel? (Ideally, please share the language of the story.)